# Regular Expression for Illegal first character

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I have an input field that uses the HTML5 pattern attribute to only allow alphanumeric characters and underscores `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`.

How do I adjust the code so that the string can't **begin** with an underscore character, yet still allow them within the remainder of the string?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Note: If my explanation above isn't clear, below is a list of valid / invalid input values.

1. has_underscore `valid`
2. _begins_with_underscore `invalid`
3. first_name `valid`
4. last_name `valid`
5. _illegal `invalid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

This is the same as the regex you had, except that `^(?!_)` means the first character cannot be an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just not include the `_` in the first group

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Or even:

```
^[^_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Comment: Ah, clever. That will work as well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JohnTiggernaught Note that for this answer to support single-letter indentifiers, the last `+` should be a `*`. Other than that, this works fine.

Comment: The second option `^[^_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` is incorrect. It will allows trash for the first character.

Comment: @nhahtdh it sows everything but _ not exactly trash

Comment: I mean it will allow any Unicode character except for _ for the first  character.